# How to make an animated segue

Tags: ios, swift

I wold like to slide multiple ViewController nicely like in the video below. (in the video there is fade animation when segue). 
How can I achieve this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMI54SuvX9Q

Comment: you are free to define custom [transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html) or [animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) anytime – the limit is your imagination only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can implement any kind of transition animation on seques, present, push etc. 
for that you will have to create a class and implement

`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`

Delegate in that class.
After that you will have to implement the following methods -

```
optional public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?


optional public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

In these methods you can write you animation code.
Here are few links that will help you to understand transition animations in more details - 
[Appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/), 
[raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173576/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-3)

Both are good tutorials and they might help you to build up some cool transition animations.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I will try :)